# Promise resolves before forEach loop completes

Tags: javascript, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I'm building my first CRUD (library) application and recently learned about promises as a means to avoid deeply-nested callbacks. I'm attempting to seed my DB with some data each time the server starts, but I seem to be missing something conceptually.

I have four objects in a `bookData` array that I want to iterate over and save to the DB using Mongoose:

```js
function seedBooks() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        bookData.forEach(function(seed){
            Book.create(seed, function(err, newBook){
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        });
        resolve();
    });
}
```

This function is one of a few that I am attempting to chain together, which is why I'm using promises. But I'm finding that `seedBooks()` resolves with anywhere between 1 and 4 of the sample books created,

```js
function seedDB() {
    removeAllBooks()
    .then(function(){
        return removeAllUsers();
    })
    .then(function(){
        return seedUsers();
    })
    .then(function(){
        return seedBooks();
    })
    .then(function(){
        return seedBookInstances();
    });
}
```

Am I understanding or using promises & resolve incorrectly? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The below explains why your code is not working and advice for, in general, how to convert non-promise code to promises. Since Mongoose produces promises, however, you should be using those instead of using `new Promise`. See [Olegzandr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47299141/1945651) regarding that.

---

The promise is resolving immediately because you are calling `resolve()` immediately.

The rule of thumb when converting non-promises to promises is to promisify the smallest part of the non-promise code. In this case, it means promisifying the code to save a single item. If you do that, the collect place to call `resolve()` becomes clear:

```
function seedBook(seed) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        Book.create(seed, function (err, newBook) {
            if (err) { reject(err); } else { resolve(newBook); }
        });
    });
}

function seedBooks() {
    return Promise.all(bookData.map(seedBook));
}
```

This also has the benefit of allowing you to access the returned `newBook`s, should you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Mongoose, you can just do this:

```
const saveBooks = function(books) {
    return books.map(function(seed) {
            return Book.create(seed);  // returns a promise
        });
    });
}

return Promise.all(saveBooks(books)).then(function(){
    // all books are saved
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resolving your Promise synchronously, right after you started your  forEached requests, which are async. You may try the following approach instead:

```
function seedBooks() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var count = 0, length = bookData.length;
        bookData.forEach(function(seed){
            Book.create(seed, function(err, newBook){
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                if(count++ >= length ) {
                  resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here the Promise is being resolved only after all async requests are done.

Another option would be just to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). In that approach you need to promisify all your requests in the loop, return an array of Promises and then call `Promise.all(_seedBooks()).then()`, where `_seedBook` returns an array of Promises:

```
function _seedBooks() {
    return bookData.map(function(seed) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            Book.create(seed, function(err, newBook) {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(newBook);
            });
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(_seedBooks())
.then(function(result) { /* result is the array of newBook objects */ })
.catch(function(error) { /* error is the first rejected err */ })
```